# How to group by custom types with linq

Tags: .net, linq, group-by

I have this class

```
public class Item
{
       public Coordinate coordinate { get; set; }
        ...
        ...
}
```

With Coordinate being define like this:

```
public class Coordinate
{
        public Coordinate(float latitude, float longitude)
        {
            Latitude = latitude;
            Longitude = longitude;
        }

        public float Latitude { get; private set; }
        public float Longitude { get; private set; }
}
```

And I want to have a linq query like that :

```
var grouped = from it in items
              group it by it.Coordinate into grp
              select grp;
```

[As mentioned here by MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384063.aspx) I thought this was possible if I would override Equals on my Coordinate class :

> Use a named type if you must pass the
>   query variable to another method.
>   Create a special class using
>   auto-implemented properties for the
>   keys, and then override the Equals 
>   and GetHashCode  methods. You can also
>   use a struct, in which case you do not
>   strictly have to override those
>   methods. For more information see How
>   to: Implement an Immutable Class That
>   Has Auto-Implemented Properties

Equals implementation for Coordinate class :

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
       var coord = obj as Coordinate;
       if(coord == null) return false;
       return (Latitude == coord.Latitude && Longitude == coord.Longitude);
}
```

still I cant get my linq query to group by similar coordinates, as my **failing** test shows :

```
[TestMethod]
public void GroupBy_3ItemsWith2DifferentCoordinates_Returns2Groups()
{
    var items = new List<Item>
        {
            new Item {Coordinate = new Coordinate(10, 10)},
            new Item {Coordinate = new Coordinate(10, 10)},
            new Item {Coordinate = new Coordinate(12, 10)},
        };
    var grouped = from it in items
                  group it by it.Coordinate into g
                  select g;
    Assert.AreEqual(2, grouped.Count());
}
```

There is an overload to the GrouBy method that takes an IEqualityComparer as a parameter, but is there the equivalent using the group clause?
Am I doing something wrong?? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You've shown the Equals implementation, but not GetHashCode. You need to override both (and in  a consistent way) for grouping to work.

Sample GetHashCode implementation:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    int hash = 23;
    hash = hash * 31 + Latitude.GetHashCode();
    hash = hash * 31 + Longitude.GetHashCode();
    return hash;
}
```

Note that comparing `float` values for exact equality is always somewhat risky - but I'd at least expect your unit tests to pass, given that they're not performing any calculations.

Comment: Just tried it, That's what I was missing. Great Thank you :)

 public override int GetHashCode()
 {
    return ((int)Latitude * 100 )^ ((int)Longitude*100);
 }

Comment: If that's what your hash code is doing, you should make sure that your equality code matches it - they should be consistent with each other.

Comment: Latitude.GetHashCode() ^ Longitude.GetHashCode() gives the same results when inverting Latitude and Longitude. So that wasn't a good solution as I want to ensure that coord(x,y) != coord(y,x);
Your code works since the order of the operations matters.
Thanks for the precision, that helped :)

Answer (score 2):

> There is an overload to the GrouBy
>   method that takes an IEqualityComparer
>   as a parameter, but is there the
>   equivalent using the group clause?

You can always group by an anonymous type, if you just want a quick inline solution and aren't worried about hitting the exact type for the keys:

```
var grouped =
  from it in items 
  group it by new {it.Coordinate.Latitude, it.Coordinate.Longitude};
```

Comment: I knew that solution, but you won't have the coordinate class as key, just an anonymous type.

Answer (score 2):

A more modern answer; In C#9/.NET6, I believe you can use record types to accomplish what anonymous types do as far as Linq comparisons, but in an automatic way.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/records

> You create record types when you want value-based equality and comparison, don't want to copy values, and want to use reference variables.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record

> For record types, including record struct and readonly record struct, two objects are equal if they are of the same type and store the same values.