# Count groups using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object called simulation results.

```
 public SimulationResult
 {
        public Horse Winner {get;set;}
        public Horse Second {get;set;}
        public Horse Third {get;set;}
        public Horse Fourth {get;set;}
  }

  public Horse
  {
        public Guid Id{get;set;}
  }
```

So, I have a list of 50000 SimulationResult. How can I determine the top 50 most common results.

I tried using LINQ groupBy but the horseId appears in each object and it doesn't allow multiple occurrences of one value.

EDIT
Sorry, thought it was clear. 
So we have 8 horses total. Say horse id is 1-8.

So in simulation result 1 the winner is 1, second is 2, third is 3, fourth is 4.

In simulation result 2 first is 5, second is 6 , third is 7, fourth is 8.

In simulation result 3 first is 1, second is 2, third is 3, fourth is 4.

So result set 1 and result set 3 are equal. So in this sample, winner 1 second 2 third 3 fourth 4 is the most common result.

Comment: I guess you need to define for us "most common"?

Comment: can you please share your table structure and provide example what exactly you want

Comment: I edited the question. Hopefully that makes it more clear.

Comment: Still not quite clear. By common you mean "equal"? Like in your example, result1 and result3?

Comment: Yes. Repetitions of the same result set.

Answer (score 3):

> I tried using LINQ groupBy but the horseId appears in each object and it doesn't allow multiple occurrences of one value.

If you mean using anonymous type as explained in [Grouping by Composite Keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384063.aspx), although most of the time we can let the compiler infer the names of us, we can always (and here it's necessary to) specify them explicitly:

```
var topResults = simulationResults
    .GroupBy(r => new
    { 
        WinnerId = r.Winner.Id,
        SecondId = r.Second.Id,
        ThirdId = r.Third.Id,
        FourthId = r.Fourth.Id,
    })
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
    .Select(g => g.First()) // or new { Result = g.First(), Count = g.Count() } if you need the count
    .Take(50)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: this is beautiful and works perfect. Do you have a source for how you came up with this, or just lots of LINQ practice?

Comment: One source is of course the link in the answer, another is [Anonymous Types (C# Programming Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx), and then of course is the experience coming with a lot of experiments and SO puzzles :)

Answer (score 1):

Simplest answer to your question:

```
class ExactResult {
    public String CombinedId { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
resultList.Select(l => {
    var combinedId = l.Winner.Id.ToString() + l.Second.Id.ToString() + l.Third.ToString() + l.Fourth.ToString();
    return new ExactResult() { CombinedId = combinedId), Count = l.Count(c => c.Winner.Id.ToString() + c.Second.Id.ToString() + c.Third.ToString() + c.Fourth.ToString();)}
}).OrderByDescending(e => e.Count).Take(50)
```

The answer is meaningless though. If what you're really going for is the most likely 4 winners from a bunch of results, this is not the way to go about it. This will just display the most results with the EXACT same 4 winners.
What you're probably looking for is statistical analysis or maybe spread. Anyway things more complicated than what you're actually asking.

Comment: I'm looking for what I described(poorly). I figured out a way to get the most common 4 winners, but i need the most likely top 4 in the exact order also.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
var q = (from x in mySimulationResultList
        group x by x into g
        let count = g.Count()
        orderby count descending
        select new { Value = g.Key, Count = count }).Take(50);

foreach (var x in q)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Value: {x.Value.ToString()} Count: {x.Count}");
}
```

If you want meaningful output for the `Console.WriteLine` you would need to override `ToString` for `Horse` and `SimulationResult`

You must override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` for `SimulationResult`, something like this:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    SimulationResult simResult = obj as SimulationResult;
    if (simResult != null)
    {
        if (Winner == simResult.Winner
            && Second == simResult.Second
            && Third == simResult.Third
            && Fourth == simResult.Fourth)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    int hash = 12;
    hash = hash * 5 + Winner.GetHashCode();
    hash = hash * 5 + Second.GetHashCode();
    hash = hash * 5 + Third.GetHashCode();
    hash = hash * 5 + Fourth.GetHashCode();
    return hash;
}
```

Sources [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454601/how-to-count-duplicates-in-list-with-linq) (group by query) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280183/how-to-group-by-custom-types-with-linq) (comparing objects against eachother)