# Linq GroupBy and select other attributes as list

Tags: c#, linq

How to group by Properties and select other properties as lists using LINQ?

I'm bad at explaining it so here's an example:

Lets say I have a list of C# objects that can be represented in JSON like this:

```
[
    { "id":123, "name":"John", "carId":1, "carAge":3 },
    { "id":123, "name":"John", "carId":2, "carAge":4 },
    { "id":4, "name":"Mary", "carId":3, "carAge":3 },
    { "id":4, "name":"Mary", "carId":4, "carAge":3 },
    { "id":123, "name":"John", "carId":5, "carAge":3 }
]
```

Among all those objects only `carId` is unique.

I would like to group them by person details and join those details with connected car details.

The end result would look like this but as c# objects:

```
[
    {"id":123, "name":"John",
        [
            {"carId":1, "carAge":3},
            {"carId":2, "carAge":4},
            {"carId":5, "carAge":3}
        ]
    },
    {"id":4, "name":"Mary",
        [
            {"carId":3, "carAge":3},
            {"carId":4, "carAge":3}
        ]
    }
]
```

**Edit:**

I'm stuck after

```
list.GroupBy(x => new { x.Id, x.Name })
```

because I don't need any aggregate functions but only selection.

I apologize for not posting more code, this is a simplified version, the real thing has more filtering and convoluted domain specific terminology.

Everything is done in memory - without DB to worry about.

Comment: Please show what you have tried. We can help from there. There are many sources to see how to group by and project

Comment: Providing a [mcve] would make things simpler, too. It looks like this is a simple `GroupBy` operation where you specific separate key and element selectors, but it would be easier to say for sure with code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280183/how-to-group-by-custom-types-with-linq should help you. Seems like grouping by the composite key - from 2 values is what you need

Comment: I understand and agree, but the actual code gets complex and I think would distract from the problem, so unfortunately this is the best I can do right now. I made this oversimplified example just so I can explain my question better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for each section of the `group _ by _` expression create an anonymous object with the fields you want.

With any of the following ways you will construct a nested collection for each of your keys - when using a `GroupBy` it is not just about aggregations but about operations on specific groups of data. One case of it is aggregation methods.

```
var result = from item in data
             group new { item.carId, item.carAge }  by new {item.id, item.name} into g
             select g;
```

Another way would be

```
var result = from item in data
             group  by new {item.id, item.name} into g
             select new {
                 g.Key,
                 Data = g.Select(i => new {i.carId, i.carAge})
             };
```

---

Using method syntax as you tried you can use the following overload:

```
var result = data.Group(k => new {k.id, k.name},
                        e => new {e.carId, e.carAge});
```

Or if not the just add a `Select` for projection:

```
var result = data.Group(k => new {k.id, k.name})
                 .Select(g => new {
                     g.Key,
                     Data = g.Select(i => new {i.carId, i.carAge})
                 });
```